# form onsubmit doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@model MVC_STORE.Models.Product

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddProduct</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="formAdd" onsubmit=" return SendData(); return false;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Serial number:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SerialNo) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SerialNo)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product name:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product price:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product quatity:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quatity) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Quatity)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" id="toAdd" value="Add product" />
        </form>

        @Html.Partial("ProductsTable")

        <script language="javascript">
            function SendData() {
                $("#status").text("Saving product, please wait..");
                var formData = $("#formAdd").serialize();
                $.post("addProduct", formData, BindData);
                $("#status").text("");
            }
        </script>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the onsubmit doesn't work for some reason, and I've read a lot of posts about it, but none of them helped me in this case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HW_MVC_STORE.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only upper- and lower- case letters and numbers.")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(5,MinimumLength=5, ErrorMessage = "Please enter 5 characters serial.")]
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }


        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only upper- and lower- case letters")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength=2, ErrorMessage="Please enter between 2 and 10 characters.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Integers only")]
        [Required]
        public string Quatity { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("^([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)|([1-9]+[0-9]*)$", ErrorMessage = "Numbers only, bigger then zero")]
        [Required]
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tried some suggestions from posts, but none of them worked.

```
<form id="formAdd" onsubmit="return SendData(); return false;">
<form id="formAdd" onsubmit="return SendData();">
<form id="formAdd" onsubmit="SendData()">
```

I don't understand why it's even calls the SendData() function, it doesn't suppose to leave the form until all the text-boxes are correctly filed.

how can I fix it or at least what is wrong with it?

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC, you do a `@Html.BeginForm`. You may want to generate a view from your model

Comment: can I give the form id in this writing?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx

I don't see here anything suitable to my needs.(id to the form and call JS function).

Comment: Did you try creating a view from your model or controller?

Comment: I'm new at this, so I work with tutorials and documentations, so I'm not quite sure what do you mean by "creating a view from your model or controller". I have a model as you can see in the post, and strongly typed view to it, and of course a controller.
 and but that little (huge) thing that the submit calls SendData() no metter what, everything else is working great.

Comment: Your three `<script>` tags below `<html>` must be moved below `<body>` tag.

Comment: didn't help. someone in my class told me that the scripts were updated so what I have isn't relevant and I should update to the new scripts and it will work (the three scripts you mention), can it be the case?

Comment: updated the scripts too.. Didn't help..

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
<form id="formAdd" onsubmit="SendData(); return false;">
```

- the function `SendData` doesn't return a value, thus `return SendData();` doesn't make sense.
- not returning false would cause a reload of the page (default action)

If the ajax POST in `SendData` is not working, we need more details on that.

Comment: tried that one too. every thing works great, the comments if you enter wrong values, the validation in the controller (ModelState.IsValid). the only problem is that when you click the submit button it calls SendData() function regardless the values in the text boxes.